# How does app signing process work for App created on the Website

Tags: android, ios, html, windows-phone-8, blackberry

I am recently checking some Website that create app online. And there is lots of option..

[TheAppBuilder](http://www.theappbuilder.com/features/)
[MobinCube](http://www.mobincube.com/)
[Appery](http://appery.io/)
[Apps-Builder](http://www.apps-builder.com/en/home)
[Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/appbuilder)
[iBuildApp](http://ibuildapp.com/)
[MobileRoadie](http://mobileroadie.com/)
[GoodBarber](http://www.goodbarber.com/)
[Appypie](http://www.appypie.com/)
[AppMachine](http://www.appmachine.com/)
[BiznessApps](http://www.biznessapps.com/)
[Appmakr](http://www.appmakr.com/)
[Shoutem](http://www.shoutem.com/)
[Appsgeyser](http://www.appsgeyser.com/)
[AmazingCart](http://amazingcart.us/)

As i understand this all site use HTML5 to create app.
But my question is that how do they sign app for distributing app on relevant app store.
Any pointer or discussion or **Tutorial** will be helpful.

Comment: An HTML5 app cannot be distributed on the Apple app store

Comment: @Paulw11 It will do, As phonegap app distributed on App store. And its using HTML5.

Comment: Phonegap uses HTML5 but this is translated into a native app - you must join the App developer program  and sign your app like any other.  It isn't "pure" html5

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes you are right, But i am talking about doing HTML5 code at user side and signing app at server side. Like all this site doing.

Comment: Ok, well for iOS you join the app dev program, create an app profile exactly as you would for a native app and then submit your keys along with your application to the web service. They generate a native app, sign it and send it back for you to submit as you would with a native app

Answer (score 3):

First of all let me explain the concept of digital signature on app.

Each and every legal app (non - cracked) app have a digital signature attached to it which is assigned by the store itself.

The Digital signature is basically an encrypted data/information of the publisher (id ,  name  credit card no. etc) as well as some credentials entered by store itself.

As You might have read in these sites you mentioned you do have to pay the developer's account fees ($99 for iOS and $25 for android).

http://www.theappbuilder.com/pricing/
So when you create app on any of these sites they need to link your developer's account as well and publish app through the respective store.

And this is how they sign and recognise app for respective store.

Hope it helped.

My first time answering a question so excuse for any mistake.